# MySQL error 1066 - Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'TAXES'

Tags: mysql

I have two `MySQL` statemenents:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.REFERENCE,PRODUCTS.NAME,PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY,PRODUCTS.PRICESELL,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNITS,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE * TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS SUBTOTAL,
       SUM((TICKETLINES.PRICE * TICKETLINES.UNITS) * TAXES.RATE) As TAXES,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE * TICKETLINES.UNITS)
        + SUM((TICKETLINES.PRICE * TICKETLINES.UNITS) * TAXES.RATE) AS GROSSTOTAL
FROM TICKETLINES
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKETS ON TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN RECEIPTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID, TAXES
WHERE RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID AND TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET
AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID
AND TICKETLINES.TAXID = TAXES.ID
GROUP BY PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.NAME,PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY,PRODUCTS.PRICESELL
ORDER BY GROSSTOTAL DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID, PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.CODE, PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.ISCOM,
       PRODUCTS.ISSCALE, PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL, PRODUCTS.TAXCAT,
       PRODUCTS.CATEGORY,PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTESET_ID, PRODUCTS.IMAGE, PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES,
       PRODUCTS.ISKITCHEN, PRODUCTS.ISSERVICE, PRODUCTS.DISPLAY, PRODUCTS.ISVPRICE,
       PRODUCTS.ISVERPATRIB, PRODUCTS.TEXTTIP, PRODUCTS.WARRANTY, PRODUCTS.STOCKUNITS,
       TAXES.NAME, TAXES.RATE, PRODUCTS.STOCKVOLUME
FROM PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_CAT ON PRODUCTS.ID=PRODUCTS_CAT.PRODUCT
JOIN TAXCATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.TAXCAT=TAXCATEGORIES.ID
JOIN TAXES ON TAXCATEGORIES.ID=TAXES.ID
ORDER BY PRODUCTS.NAME
```

Now, I am trying to combine these two statements into one, here is what I've got:

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID, PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, PRODUCTS.CODE, PRODUCTS.NAME, PRODUCTS.ISCOM,
       PRODUCTS.ISSCALE, PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY, PRODUCTS.PRICESELL, PRODUCTS.TAXCAT,
       PRODUCTS.CATEGORY, PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTESET_ID, PRODUCTS.IMAGE, PRODUCTS.ATTRIBUTES,
       PRODUCTS.ISKITCHEN, PRODUCTS.ISSERVICE, PRODUCTS.DISPLAY, PRODUCTS.ISVPRICE,
       PRODUCTS.ISVERPATRIB, PRODUCTS.TEXTTIP, PRODUCTS.WARRANTY, PRODUCTS.STOCKUNITS,
       TAXES.NAME, TAXES.RATE, PRODUCTS.STOCKVOLUME,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNITS,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE*TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS SUBTOTAL,
       SUM((TICKETLINES.PRICE*TICKETLINES.UNITS)*TAXES.RATE) AS TAXESTOTAL,
       SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE*TICKETLINES.UNITS)
         +SUM((TICKETLINES.PRICE*TICKETLINES.UNITS)*TAXES.RATE) AS GROSSTOTAL
FROM TICKETLINES
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_CAT ON PRODUCTS.ID=PRODUCTS_CAT.PRODUCT
JOIN TAXCATEGORIES ON PPRODUCTS.TAXCAT=TAXCATEGORIES.ID
JOIN TAXES ON TAXCATEGORIES.ID=TAXES.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT=PRODUCTS.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKETS ON TICKETS.ID=TICKETLINES.TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN RECEIPTS ON RECEIPTS.ID=TICKETS.ID, TAXES
WHERE RECEIPTS.ID=TICKETS.ID AND TICKETS.ID=TICKETLINES.TICKET
AND TICKETLINES.PRODUCT=PRODUCTS.ID
AND TICKETLINES.TAXID=TAXES.ID
ORDER BY PRODUCTS.NAME
```

Why upper statement does not execute and reports error `Error Code: 1066. Not unique table/alias: 'TAXES'`
?

Comment: Remove `, TAXES`, unless there's a logical reason to join with the table twice. (Doesn't look like there is). It's basically complaining that you're selecting from the same table twice, and using the same name for each - it needs the name to be unique, which you'd do by providing an alias for the 2nd table, eg: `FROM TAXES AS TAXES2`

Comment: As Marco already stated you got `taxes` two times, so need to alias them. Additionally: never mix JOIN-syntax with old-style comma delimited, the final `taxes` will probably change the result to inner joins.

Comment: @Phil I've removed `, TAXES` and now I get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'PRODUCTS.ID' in 'on clause'`. Why?! Table `PRODUCTS` is `JOIN`ed so `PRODUCTS.ID` must be found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have 2 times `TAXES` in your `FROM` clause (here between **):

```
FROM TICKETLINES
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS_CAT ON PRODUCTS.ID=PRODUCTS_CAT.PRODUCT
JOIN TAXCATEGORIES ON PPRODUCTS.TAXCAT=TAXCATEGORIES.ID
JOIN **TAXES** ON TAXCATEGORIES.ID=TAXES.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT=PRODUCTS.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKETS ON TICKETS.ID=TICKETLINES.TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN RECEIPTS ON RECEIPTS.ID=TICKETS.ID, **TAXES**
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT interview_schedule.id AS interview_schedule,
interview_schedule.interviewdate as date,
job_profile.job_title AS Job_title,
employer.name AS Recruiter_name,
candidate.name AS candidate_name,
interviewer.name AS interviewer_name,
interview_assesment.result AS result,
interview_schedule.interview_type AS interview_Type,
interview_schedule.selling_cost AS price,
company.company_name AS company_name
 FROM interview_schedule 
 INNER JOIN  interview_schedule  ON interview_schedule.id
 INNER JOIN  interview_schedule  ON interview_schedule.interviewdate
 INNER JOIN  job_profile         ON  (job_profile.job_title=interview_schedule.jobprofile_id)
 INNER JOIN  employer            ON (employer.name=interview_schedule.employer_id)
 INNER JOIN  candidate           ON  (candidate.name=interview_schedule.candidate_id)
 INNER JOIN  interviewer         ON  (interviewer.name=interview_schedule.interviewer_id)
 INNER JOIN  interview_assesment ON (interview_assesment.result=interview_schedule.interview_schedule_id)
 INNER JOIN  interview_schedule  ON interview_schedule.interview_type
 INNER JOIN  interview_schedule  ON interview_schedule.selling_cost
 INNER JOIN  Company             ON (company.company_name=interview_schedule.company_id)
 WHERE company.id=183;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).